# UIScrollView vs. UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

For a vertical scroller are there any advantages to using UIScrollView over UITableView?

I ask because I am currently using two vertical UIScrollViews with UIImageViews inside of them and am having memory issues and poor scrolling performance. I am not doing much with the scrollers, only highlighting images as they scroll into the center of the scrollviews and adding a delete button above an image if the user wants to remove it. I've started to look at lazy image loading/reuse and it seems that most of these issues have already been resolved in the UITableView class, so I'm wondering if there's any reason to stick with UIScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a UIScrolLView with no problem if you just, like you said, lazy load the controllers, when scrolling (assuming your views are full size) you dont need to have more than 3  views loaded at any one time, all you need is the current view, the view that goes behind it and infront of it, as you scroll your view you can unload and load the appropriate views. You should look into Page Control sample application, it does exactly this and you can pretty much get all the lazy loading code from there. Link is here https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/PageControl/index.html